# Flushing not saving data in a database

Tags: hibernate, flush

When I flush stuff externally, it doesn't save it in a database. For example the code below doesn't save it in the DB:

```
public class save {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        emp a=new emp("klds","asda",12231);
        emp b=new emp("asd","asd",213);
        emp c=new emp("ERTE", "retre", 1323434);
        Session session=myfactory.getSession();
        session.save(a);
        session.save(b);
        session.save(c);
        session.flush();
        session.clear();

    }
```

But when I use transactions, it does save it in a DB. Why does it do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flush` is just `synchronization` with the db and then you need to `commit` to see the changes.

And if you do just `commit` .It automatically `flushes` and you can see your changes from another session too.

when we call `session.flush()` our statements will `execute` in database but will not be `committed`.

but if  we dont call `flush()` method on session object and if we directly call `commit` method....`commit` will internally call `flush`(do the work of executing statements on the database) and then `committing`.

so `commit=flush+commit`

so when we call method `flush()` on Session object then it will not `commit` but hits the database and `executes` the query and `rollback` the same

so to commit we must use `commit()` on `Transaction` object

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `FlushMode` of the session to `MANUAL`:

```
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL)
```